# How to force VoiceOver to not read the "heading" word for view controller title

Tags: ios, objective-c, accessibility, voiceover

Is There any way to force VoiceOver to not read view controller title "heading" word after reading title/accessibilityLabel?

Currently the behaviour is default. If I set title to "My Panel" voice over will read something like this:

"My Panel"...."Heading"

I believe this is the result of accessibility trait UIAccessibilityTraitHeader set on some of the UI element but I don't know exacly which element has this trait. My view controller in nested inside navigation controller. Please don't ask why I need to remove this one speaking word. That is the requirement and I need to get rid of it.

Comment: You should reassess that requirement. Why are you trying to create a lesser experience? The heading trait is not just a piece of information, but also used for fast navigation. A user of your app could (using the rotor) enter a mode where they jump from heading to heading.

Comment: You should listen to David, he's a smart guy.

Answer (score 0):

David's comment is the correct answer. You should use the `UIElement` classes semantically. In other words, if the text "My Panel" is not a heading for the view, then what is it semantically? Once you have the answer for that  question, then you can redesign your view to use that type of element, styled appropriately.

However, from all the information you have given, it appears as though it is semantically a heading and therefore the screen reader is doing the appropriate thing.

Whoever gave you that requirement may not know what they are talking about. This type of requirement often comes from people who are new to accessible UI/UX design.

Answer (score 0):

You can customise this headerview, and implement the `accessibilityElementDidBecomeFocused` method in your custom view, when this view did become focused and post `UIAccessibilityLayoutChangedNotification` to `VoiceOver` and focus to itself, and then return the traits `UIAccessibilityTraitNone`

```
- (void)accessibilityElementDidBecomeFocused {
       UIAccessibilityPostNotification(UIAccessibilityLayoutChangedNotification,   self);
}

- (UIAccessibilityTraits)accessibilityTraits {
    return UIAccessibilityTraitNone;
}
```